# Cech cohomology with respect to different sheaf.

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, complex-geometry

I am just wondering

Can I compute 
$H^1(\mathbb P^2,\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(1))$? if yes, how? Note that the sheaf is not on $\mathbb P^2$, but on $\mathbb P^1$

Also is there a sheaf with this notation?
$T_{1,2}$

Thanks

Comment: What is your definition of $H^1(X,F)$ where $F$ is not a sheaf on $X$ ?

Comment: I don't have any definition, that's my question. I am sorry if I said it wrong.

Comment: I think I am supposed to ask, is this a sheaf?, thanks for reply

Comment: Your question simply does not make sense, since $H^1(X,F)$ has a meaning only when $F$ is a sheaf on $X$.

Comment: It would probably be better if you explained what to you are trying to accomplish with this.

Comment: I just was copying this question a while ago, and then start to solve it, then I start doubting myself that I copied it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If $j:\mathbb P^1\hookrightarrow \mathbb P^2$ is a linear embedding one has the following formula, which might answer your question:   $$H^1(\mathbb P^2,j_*\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(1))=H^1(\mathbb P^1,\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(1))=0 \quad (\bigstar)$$ 
Note that $j_*\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(1)$ is a coherent sheaf on $\mathbb P^2$ of which it is perfectly legitimate to compute the cohomology.

2) The relevant context is probably the exact sequence of sheaves on $\mathbb P^2$: $$0\to \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^2}(-1)\to \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^2}\to j_*\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}\to 0$$ which after twisting by $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^2}(1)$ yields $$0\to \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^2}\to \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^2}(1)\to j_*\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(1)\to 0$$

3) In general, if a closed subvariety (or subscheme) $j:Y\hookrightarrow X$ is given by the quasi-coherent ideal sheaf $\mathcal I_Y$, the following exact sequence obtains: $$ 0\to  \mathcal I_Y   \to \mathcal O_X\to j_*\mathcal O_Y\to 0              $$ However  algebraic geometers usually write just $$ 0\to  \mathcal I_Y   \to \mathcal O_X\to \mathcal O_Y\to 0              $$  omitting the $j_*$.   This abuse of language can, unfortunately,  be a source of confusion.

Comment: Thank you so much, and the first cohomolgy group of $\mathbb P^1$ with respect to $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(1)$ is zero in relation star since we have no constant in the homogenous polynomials?

Comment: Dear Naturemath, no, it is more complicated than that: you can prove $H^1(\mathbb P^1,\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(1))=0$ either by a little computation in Čech cohomology or by invoking Serre duality which says that $H^1(\mathbb P^1,\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(1))$ is isomorphic to the dual of  $H^0(\mathbb P^1,\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(-3))=0$ [and taking into account that the canonical bundle of $\mathbb P^1$ is  $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(-2)$].